# ethereum solc will not compile even an empty contract

Tags: solidity

I am trying to compile an empty contract
    `pragma solidity ^0.4.25;
    contract Voting {}`

When I try to compile the above, I get the following error
`"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"* Line 1, Column 1\\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.....`

I am new to solc, and I cannot figure what the problem is

I am trying to compile inside node

I have run into this problem multiple times, and I have been unsuccessful in compiling any solidity contract. Any help/pointers would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? Like how you read the contract file?

Comment: I am following Mahesh's blog, where I do the following steps:mahesh@projectblockchain:~/hello_world_voting$ node
> Web3 = require('web3')
> web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));> code = fs.readFileSync('Voting.sol').toString()
> solc = require('solc')
> compiledCode = solc.compile(code)

Comment: Does the above help. I am on the latest node.

Comment: In `readFileSync` provide the encoding of the file as well, and pass the result as is to solc without calling `toString()`.

Comment: code = fs.readFileSync('Voting.sol', 'utf8')

Comment: code = fs.readFileSync('Voting.sol', 'utf8') , and the rest of the code, but I got the same error. Missing something here.

Comment: Ok, I loaded solc version 0.4.25 "npm install solc@0.4.25", and it started compilng. Thank you for all the help, nikos. Regards.